# libgdx - json parsing custom class into array

Tags: java, json, libgdx

I have a .json file that looks like this:

```
[{
    t: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 0
},
{
    t: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 0
}]
```

And I have a class:

```
class HexTile {
    int x,y,t;
}
```

And I have an array:

```
Array<HexTile> hexTiles
```

How do I parse the contents of that file into objects and put them into this array?

Comment: I don't know whether general Gson and Jackson tutorials are applicable to what's in Libgdx, and the documentation of Libgdx is inadequate (at least for me to understand how to use it). But thanks for making an effort, have a nice day.

Comment: You don't need anything special for LibGDX, just parse it with a json parser and create your objects. You can do it manually or can write and adapter for Json or Jackson.

Comment: How can I parse that file? `fromJson()` method requires a class, but in the file it's the array of objects of that class.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401431/libgdx-json-parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the class name to your array elements so the Json parser knows what to turn them into:

```
[{
    class: com.yourpackage.HexTile,
    t: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 0
},
{
    class: com.yourpackage.HexTile,
    t: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 0
}]
```

Then you can load them like this. I think libgdx's Json parser always uses the ArrayList class for arrays.

```
Json json = new Json();
ArrayList<HexTile> hexTiles = json.fromJson(ArrayList.class, Gdx.files.internal("myJsonFile.json"));
```

If you need them as a libgdx Array, the only way I know to convert it is kind of ugly:

```
Array<HexTile> arrayTiles = new Array<HexTile>(tiles.toArray(new HexTile[tiles.size()]));
```

---

**Second method - use a wrapper class**

This method reduces clutter in your json file. Create a wrapper class to hold your array:

```
public class HexTileArrayWrapper {
    public Array<HexTile> array;
}
```

And structure your json file with this array element wrapping it:

```
{
array:
[{
    t: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 0
},
{
    t: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 0
}]
}
```

Then you can load it like this:

```
HexTileArrayWrapper arrayWrapper = json.fromJson(HexTileArrayWrapper.class, file);
Array<HexTile> arrayTiles = arrayWrapper.array;
```